# MySql Group by Month

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have set of dates and it's corresponding sales and I want to go group my month with order by month.
Not it may be possible that entry of few months can not be present and if so then for corresponding months value will be 0 else what ever sum available for other month.

Comment: do you want months to be displayed from 1-12? and if there is entry for the month than sum the values, and if there is not than for example show month:2 sum:0 ?

Comment: Yeah 1-12 entries.If there is entry then sum else 0..along with group by and sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this would maybe do a trick: - but you need to take care of years, this is only month based

```
SELECT s1.m as mnth,IFNULL(s2.smv,0) as smv FROM
(SELECT 1 as m UNION 
SELECT 2 UNION 
SELECT 3 UNION 
SELECT 4 UNION 
SELECT 5 UNION 
SELECT 6 UNION 
SELECT 7 UNION 
SELECT 8 UNION 
SELECT 9 UNION 
SELECT 10 UNION 
SELECT 11 UNION 
SELECT 12) s1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT MONTH(startdatum) as mnth, 
SUM(somevalue) as smv
FROM db_table GROUP BY mnth) s2
ON s1.m=s2.mnth
```

Comment: Working..You did with ease :)

Answer (score 0):

YOU can try:
//this will give you all entries for the required month

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE date=MONTH('datecolumn_name') ORDER BY MONTH(datecolumn_name) ASC;
```

Comment: You are not getting what I am asking..!If month Feb,March entry is not found then it will return 0 for that month else whatever sum achieved will be result

Answer (score 0):

juz run thiz query u get idea :

(SELECT @d:=date_add(@d,interval 1 MONTH) AS month_view,date_format(@c,'%b-%Y') AS month_name,@a:= @c AS month_start,@b:=if(last_day(@a)>'2014-02-24','2014-02-24', last_day(@a)) AS month_end, @c:= CASE WHEN date_add(@b,interval 1 DAY)>'2014-02-24' THEN NULL ELSE date_add(@b , INTERVAL 1 DAY) END AS dummy_val FROM table_name,
(SELECT @c:='2013-01-01', @d:='2013-01-01') AS month_temp WHERE @c IS NOT NULL)

'table_name' give any table name from ur database

from_date=2013-01-01 
to_date=2014-02-24